# Can't access Front End Editing for articles of a category blog

Tags: front-end, category-blog, editing, joomla-3.10

When I login on the front end of my Joomla-Site, I can only edit articles that are shown in a menu-item-type "single article". Those articles that are shown in a menu-item-type "category blog" can't be edited. In fact, they are missing the edit-icon (gearwheel).

Funny though: If I enable "Show Publish Date", so that a bit of space is added on the top of an article, the gearwheel appears (Date on the left hand side/ gearwheel on the right hand side). Publish Dates (any dates at all) are usually disabled on my site. Articles of a menu-item-type "single article" have the gearwheel, regardless of the Publish Date.

I recently updated the system from Joomla 3.5 to 3.10.11 This problem appears since then. My User has Super-User-permissions.

Am I missing a certain setting? I've searched up and down...